# Union aggregate datemultiranges in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a `datemultirange` type.
I want to combine (compute the union) of multiple rows.

```
SELECT
  type_id,
  range_agg(some_date_ranges)
FROM foo
GROUP BY type_id
```

My table foo looks something like this:

| id (int) | some_date_ranges(datemultirange) | type_id (int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {[2016-07-02,2016-07-24),[2017-10-05,2017-10-12),[2018-05-23,2021-03-08)} | 4 |
| 2 | {[2016-07-03,2016-07-24),[2017-10-03,2017-10-13),[2018-05-23,2021-04-08)} | 4 |
| 2 | {[2016-07-27,2016-07-28),[2017-10-02,2017-10-14),[2018-05-23,2021-05-08)} | 5 |

If I try to run the function above, I get the error `function range_agg(datemultirange) does not exist`. Similar with the function `aggregate_union`.

The only solution I've found so far is with a CTE that uses `unnest` and then using `range_agg` after that. But it's inelegant. Is there a better way?

## Details

- Postgres 14

Comment: What version of Postgres? `range_agg()` is in version 15+ per [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-aggregate.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I’ll have to check when I’m back home but the function does exist because I can run it after running unnest in a cte. So I think postgres just means that the function does exist for multirange and i think that’s correct. It only exists for range.

Comment: I should have been clearer `range_agg(anymultirange)` exists in 15+, `range_agg(anyrange)` exists in 14+.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver YES! It was a PG 14 problem! Hero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres 14 as simple as I could get it is something like:

```
create table multi_range_test(date_mr datemultirange);
insert into 
    multi_range_test 
values 
    ('{[2016-07-02,2016-07-24),[2017-10-05,2017-10-12), [2018-05-23,2021-03-08)}'::datemultirange), 
    ('{[2016-07-03,2016-07-24),[2017-10-03,2017-10-13),[2018-05-23,2021-04-08)}'::datemultirange) ,
    ('{[2016-07-27,2016-07-28),[2017-10-02,2017-10-14),[2018-05-23,2021-05-08)}'::datemultirange);

select range_agg(mr) from (select unnest(date_mr) from multi_range_test) as t(mr) ;
                                             range_agg                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {[07/02/2016,07/24/2016),[07/27/2016,07/28/2016),[10/02/2017,10/14/2017),[05/23/2018,05/08/2021)}
```

Compared to `range_agg(anymultirange)` in Postgres 15:

```
select range_agg(date_mr) from multi_range_test ;
                                             range_agg                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {[07/02/2016,07/24/2016),[07/27/2016,07/28/2016),[10/02/2017,10/14/2017),[05/23/2018,05/08/2021)}
```